Why does a scalar field with mass much greater than the Hubble parameter stay near its minimum during inflation?"
If a scalar field $\chi$ (not the inflaton) is present during inflation, and if the mass of this field is much larger than the Hubble parameter $H$ during inflation, the field will stay near its minimum, $\chi=0$. Why don't quantum fluctuations become significant in this case?
